# PHP, Check if a value is in an array

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

This is probably very easy but I cannot get it to work in php.
What I need is the following (written explanatory)

```
if ( 11 is in array(1,3,4,6,7,8,9,11,34,45,56,77) ) : return true;
```

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Tried searching? I mean, really, like, searching Google for "php check in array".

Comment: :) .. love those comments .. of course I did .. but human help is invaluable .. always gets the right results

Comment: FYI humans are not perfect. Not everyone will have the right answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$answer = in_array($number,$array);
```

`$answer` is a boolean.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
if (in_array(11, $your_array)) {}
```

See: [PHP's in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) which has a method signature of:

```
bool in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = FALSE ] )
```

The `$needle` being the value you are looking for, in this instance `11` and the `$haystack` being the array that you want to search.  If you pass `true` for the final parameter, you are telling PHP to only use the type that you've specified in `$needle`.

For instance, if you pass `"11"` and set `$strict` to `true`, it would not find `11`.

Answer (score 0):

This'll do it!

```
$input = array(1,3,4,6,7,8,9,11,34,45,56,77);

$output = array_filter($input, function($var) {
    return ($var == 11);}
);
```

Comment: Way too much processing for suck a simple request. in_array is a better function.

Comment: Answers above are better than this example with the specific circumstances you've set. If you want to check for multiple values in the array, use the above but change ($var == 11) to ($var >= 10) for example will return an array with all values above or equal to 10. EDIT: :) Spot on Lucas

Comment: I still prefer using a foreach and in_array. It's cheaper, processor-wise.